# function to set UILabel text from float not correctly updating when setting self (only works with super)

Tags: ios, swift, super

I've got a function like so on a subclass of UILabel:

```
func setTextFromFloat(amount: Float) {
    super.text = formatCurrency(fromFloat: amount)
}
```

And another:

```
internal func formatCurrency(fromFloat amount: Float) -> String {
    let currencyFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    print(currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(float: amount))!)
    return currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(float: amount))!
}
```

And an override init:

```
override internal var text: String? {
    didSet {
        super.text = formatCurrency(fromString: self.text)
    }
}
```

I can then call:

```
myLabel.setTextFromFloat(2.5)
```

And it works.

It wasn't working originally though, because first I tried to set `self.text` in the `setTextFromFloat()` method instead of `super.text`. Why did I have to change it to set `super`? Why didn't `self` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This looks as an interview question ;-)

The problem is basically that you are overriding `var text` stored variable and adding an observer (*via `didSet`*) that basically rewrites every time the same value in an infinite loop (if you were calling **`self`** in that line instead of **`super`**)

It works for `super` because you are relying on the implementation that **Do Not** have that observer to set data in place.

A quick solution is to remove that observer, either way, you are calling `setTextFromFloat(amount: Float)` that gets the job done.

> **A quick snippet solving the problem follows**:

```
class ExtendedLabel : UILabel {
    func setTextFromFloat(amount: Float) {
        self.text = formatCurrency(fromFloat: amount)
    }
    internal func formatCurrency(fromFloat amount: Float) -> String {
        let currencyFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let formattedFloat = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(float: amount))!
        print(formattedFloat)
        return formattedFloat
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var lab : ExtendedLabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        lab.setTextFromFloat(2.5)
    }
}
```

Either way, you may want to think at this as a possible **extension**, and refactor the code as such.

Comment: Ha interview question! I'll have to add it to my list. I totally actually encountered this problem on my own this morning lol!